# iPhone - create animation like Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation

I'd like to create an animation in iPhone app,
this animation will look like Xcode's one when it's verifying the application.

Do you know how to do it?

[image: Verifying application]

Comment: ^ How nice... Anyway here at Stackoverflow we assist you with your problems, but we will not solve the entire thing for you.  You should also mention which programming language you even want to use? Objective-C?

Comment: Yes, with Objective C. I'd like to create this animation in my sample iPhone application.

Comment: If you subclass UIProgressView, you might be able to put some kind of marquee gif inside it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for :
[YLProgressBar](https://github.com/YannickL/YLProgressBar)